# How do you reset ftp password in vim?

Tags: vim, ftp

Assume I want to access this remote file in vim

`ftp://amr@steamboy//home/amr/bin/dr_snapshot.py`

and, when prompted, I accidentally enter the wrong password.

How do I reset the password? Right now I have to exit from and restart vim.

The client and server are both on Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: Beside restarting VIM, I think this is a good question. :)

Comment: Good comment; I've edited to reflect it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:help netrw-userpass`

> > > ```
> > > Attempts to use ftp will prompt you for a user-id and a password.
> > > These will be saved in global variables |g:netrw_uid| and
> > > |s:netrw_passwd|; subsequent use of ftp will re-use those two strings,
> > > thereby simplifying use of ftp.  However, if you need to use a
> > > different user id and/or password, you'll want to call |NetUserPass()|
> > > first.
> > > ```

I.e. use:

```
:call NetUserPass()                     -- prompts for uid and password
```

PS.

vim comes with an amazing help-system. In this case I did
`:h ftp`, did a search for `password` and first hit was this section:

> > > The script attempts to get passwords for ftp invisibly using |inputsecret()|,
> > >       a built-in Vim function.  See |netrw-userpass| for how to change the password
> > >       after one has set it.

which gave the entry for **netrw-userpass**

BTW If you are lost, do a `:h <SOME_STRING>` and press CTRL-d and vim displays a list with all section containing that string...

Comment: At least in the version of vim I'm using (7.3), that command can be simplified to just :NetUserPass, rather than bothering with call.